# PHP For loop not producing output

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

simple php for loop, worked fine before the loop was added, but I want it to print 4 rows of 3 products. Problem is its putting all 12 items into a single row! Then it creates 3 more empty rows at the bottom of the page.

Added updated version of the code, figured it might help someone else, although it displays correctly I have to pull 15 records from the table.

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) { ?>
            <div class="row products">
                <?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)) : ?>

                <!-- product-->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="product">
                        <div class="image">
                            <a href="#"><img src=" <?= "images/wheels/wheelphotos/". $product["bigpic"]; ?>" alt= "<?= $product["manufacturer"]; ?>" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            <div class="quick-view-button"><button type="button" onclick="quickModal(<?= $product["recid"]; ?>)"  class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Quick view</button></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <p class="brand"><a href="#"><?= $product["manufacturer"]; ?></a></p>
                            <h3> <a href="detail.html"><?= $product["diam"]; ?></a></h3>
                            <p class="price">$<?= $product["rrp"]; ?></p>
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-primary">Details</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>


<?php for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) { ?>
            <div class="row products">
                <?php
                $j = 0;
                while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)) :
                $j++;
                    if($j > 3 ){
                        break;
                    }
                ?>
                <!-- product-->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="product">
                        <div class="image">
                            <a href="#"><img src=" <?= "images/wheels/wheelphotos/". $product["bigpic"]; ?>" alt= "<?= $product["manufacturer"]; ?>" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            <div class="quick-view-button"><button type="button" onclick="quickModal(<?= $product["recid"]; ?>)"  class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Quick view</button></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <p class="brand"><a href="#"><?= $product["manufacturer"]; ?></a></p>
                            <h3> <a href="detail.php"><?= $product["diam"]; ?></a></h3>
                            <p class="price">$<?= $product["rrp"]; ?></p>
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-primary" href="detail.php">Details</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop is going to run for as many records as your query selected. If you need to get out of that loop after a certain number of records, you can use a variable to count how many times you've been through the loop, then `break` out of the while loop. Your `for` loop will go through its next iteration and print the "row" div, and the `while` loop will process the next couple of records until you `break` again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, my problem is I'm not used to writing php, and am struggling with integrating php logic with html output, where would I put the if statement with a break? I've just tried adding it in with the while loop to no success, also why is everyone down voting the question, php as a whole has few examples of integrating php with html on their website and just straight php syntax.